# Accessing a returned list in the main method

Tags: java, list

So basically I have a static class that returns a newly made list and what I need to do is print each element of said list by using it in the main method. I get the error that cant solve blablabla to a variable which I guess means that the list I am trying to use is not usable yet. Thought it might be a good idea to add the last lines here as well for a visual.
The error code given is "b cannot be resolved to a variable".

```
public class A5P5 {
public static int[] teine(int arv, int alum, int ylem) {
    int [] b = new int[arv];
    for (int i = 0; i < arv; i++) {
        double k = Math.random() * (ylem-alum) + alum;
        int l = (int)k;
        b[i] = l;
    }
    return b;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double x = Math.random() * (110-50) + 50;
        int y = (int)x;
        a[i] = y;
    }
    for (int elem: a) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    teine(20, 20, 40);
    for (int elem: b) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Let's see your code and what you've got so far.

Comment: Does that mean you wish to see the whole code?

Comment: How about relevant code.

Comment: Your static method returning the List<> and your main method where you use it should be sufficient.

Comment: Why not just present your code and paste the exact `error message` you got instead of typing **blablabla** ?

Comment: It would appear you don't understand the very basics of programming. Your method *returns* an array. You don't assign that to anything in `main()`. I would highly suggest a beginner's book on Java (or programming).

Comment: Yeah sorry. I've been taking java for a whole 2 weeks. All in all, if you think a book would help me in a great way and it's available online then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
...<delete teine(20, 20, 40);>...
for (int elem: teine(20, 20, 40)) {...
```

you have to assign the value returned from the method above so an alternative would be:

```
int[] b = teine(20, 20, 40);
for (int elem: b) {...
```

Comment: Most of these explanations made me feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot acces `b` because it is a local var in your `teine` method, so that won't work in main:

```
teine(20, 20, 40);
for (int elem: b) {
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

but since teine returns your `b` anyway you can just do this:

```
for (int elem: teine(20, 20, 40)) {
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

To start that isn't a List it's an Array. They are quite different.

Now about your issue. You are making a new int array in your main but not populating it with anything so (according to the specs) each element has a value of 0.

You need to actually call and assign your array. `int[] a = teine(arv, alum, ylem)` would be a good place to start moving forward with your program.

I would also agree with @Brian Roach that you may need to brush up on your basics. Also try using more descriptive names for your variables. It will help both people reading your code and yourself when you come back to the code down the line and need to debug or modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and yeah list/array - I'm still kind of thinking about python so I haven't really gotten used to the new terms.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the compilation error is about this line:

```
for (int elem: b) {
```

Hints:

1. Which `b` do you think that refers to?
2. The `b` declared in your `tiene` method is *out of scope* at that point.  Specifically, the variable `b` goes out of scope when the call to `tiene` finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the wake up call! Now that I think about it, my question seems kind of dumb haha.

Comment: @user3240759 - If there is a lesson here for you, it is that is important to think carefully / clearly when programming.  Read the error message, and try to understand what they are actually saying.  In this case, the compiler has told you the literal truth.  In that context, `b` *doesn't* resolve to anything at all.  To solve the problem, you needed to think about *why* it doesn't resolve.